# Color is not changing with this.customStyle

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I can not get the paper tabs selection bar to change color when I invoke `changeColor()`. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<dom-module id="paper-tabs-custom">
  <style>
        paper-tabs {
      --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: white;
    }

    paper-tab {
      --paper-tab-content-unselected: {
        opacity: 1.0;
      }
    }

    paper-tab {
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    paper-tab[name="portfolio"] {
      width: 161px;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <paper-tabs noink="true" 
      attr-for-selected="name"
      selected="{{setSelected}}">
      <paper-tab data-name="home" data-px="240" name="home" on-tap="jumpToPage">
        HOME
      </paper-tab>
      <paper-tab data-name="portfolio" data-px="180" name="portfolio" on-tap="jumpToPage">
        PORTFOLIO
     </paper-tabs>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "paper-tabs-custom",
      changeColor: function() {
        this.customStyle['--paper-tabs-selection-bar-color'] = 'black';
        this.updateStyles();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: The style tag should be inside the template tag. (should work outside as well though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to set the property on `<paper-tabs>` directly and call `updateStyles` directly on it as well. Might be that just calling `updateStyles` on it directly will do the trick, but I am quite sure that's where the mistake is.

```
this.$.tabs.customStyle['--paper-tabs-selection-bar-color'] = 'black';
this.$.tabs.updateStyles();
```